# Cradlepoint IBR1100 Router Randumly Looses GPS Position

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, gps

I have an IBR1100 CradlePoint router on a Truck in Ontario, Canada. The router reports back to a server the GPS of the vehicle.

On occasion the GPS fails. No clear pattern. We run 12 Routers. A few have failed on rare occasions, one router fails every month or two.

When the GPS fails, the router is still connected to the carrier, and there are no server side errors in receiving the GPS.

Checking logs remotely via SMS returns:

`ID9,2018-09-13 10:18:22: lost position
ID10,2018-09-13 10:18:22: No gps sample`

Rebooting of the router remotely via SMS command always corrects the problem. The most recent instance, we rebooted just the Modem, which also corrected the problem. The Modem does have the latest Firmware.

I can not find any internet literature on these logs, and CradlePoint support has not been much help.

Question is, what is the cause? Or what settings changes can I try?

*If there is a more appropriate Stack Exchange to post this question to, please let me know.*

Comment: These routers I presume are running a Linux kernel?  So are the required services still running when this behavior happens?  The fact a reboot resolves the issue points to a service issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the IBR1100 is a CradlePoint Series 3 router. Series 3 routers run the Linux software platform on firmware 4.0.3 or later. I will check what services are required and which ones are running. Since this only occurs every month or two it may be awhile before I have an update.